# ValueEventLisener not firing in JobService

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JobService meant send notifications if they are not yet seen. I have done this before with a background service but JobService am told is a more reliable way of doing it as android kills background services after a while. But all the firebase Event listeners won't fire in the JobService

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Notifications");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                NotificationModel model = dataSnapshot.getValue(NotificationModel.class);

                if (Prevalent.CURRENT_USER != null) {
                    if (model.getNotificationTo() != null) {
                        if (model.getNotificationTo().equals(Prevalent.CURRENT_USER.getUid())) {
                            if (!model.isSeen()) {
                                NotificationHelperClass.sendNotification(getApplicationContext(),
                                        model.getTitle(), model.getDescription());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
```

So I set up break points with dummy variable through this service and it never reached the first line of code in the event listener. I tested the same for the childEventListener and singleValueEventListener. I don't know whats wrong

Comment: Why are you returning `false` from `onStartJob`? The [`onStartJob` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService#onStartJob(android.app.job.JobParameters)) state that returning false means your job has already finished by the time the method returns.

Comment: Step 1 is to stop ignoring potential errors and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. Even if it isn't throwing an error now, you should implement so that we can all know there is no error.